# Subtraction in c#?

Tags: c#

I cannot subtract items form my dictionary in c#

This is the code, i am trying to get the fruits.Count as an int.

```
public class test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int totalStock = 10;`

        Dictionary<string, int> fruits = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        fruits.Add("Apples", 3);
        fruits.Add("pears", 4);
        int fruitsCount = fruits["Apples" + "pears"];
        if(fruitsCount > totalStock){
            Console.WriteLine("You have too many fruits! Please get rid of " + fruitsCount - totalStock + " fruits");
        }
        else if(fruitsCount = totalStock){
            Console.WriteLine("You have just the right amount of fruits!");
        }
        else{
            Console.WriteLine("You can fit " + totalStock - fruitsCount + " fruits");
        }

    }
}
```

But im getting errors:

> exit status 1 main.cs(14,21): error CS0019: Operator `-' cannot be
> applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'
>
> main.cs(16,10): error
> CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'
>
> main.cs(20,21):
> error CS0019: Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type
> 'string' and 'int'

Comment: It appears the elseif has a problem also - you try to assing `fruitStock = totalStock` instead compare them.

Comment: The dictionary is accesed by the key, in your case is is of type `string`. Int this line `int fruitsCount = fruits["Apples" + "pears"]` you are concatenating two strings so you are trying to access a product named `fruits["Applespears"]` which is not in the dictionary. Change it into `int fruitsCount = fruits["Apples"] + fruits["pears"]`

Comment: The equality comparer in c# is `==` instead `=`

Comment: The "`Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'`" is because of `"... rid of " + fruitsCount - totalStock + " fruits"` You must do some type conversion manually or use a new variable, I would `int excessOfFruit = fruitsCount - totalStock` and use that variable in the Console.WriteLine instruction.

Answer (score 2):

You *don't have* `"Apples" + "pears" == "Applespears"` fruit, that's why

```
fruits["Apples" + "pears"];
```

is wrong. Put it as `fruits["Apples"] + fruits["pears"];`:

```
public static void Main() {
  int totalStock = 10;

  Dictionary<string, int> fruits = new Dictionary<string, int>() {
    {"Apples", 3},       
    {"pears", 4},
  };

  // Either Apples + pears
  int fruitsCount = fruits["Apples"] + fruits["pears"];
  // ... Or sum of all the fruits
  // int fruitsCount = fruits.Values.Sum();

  if (fruitsCount > totalStock){
    Console.WriteLine($"You have too many fruits! Please get rid of {fruitsCount - totalStock} fruits");
  }
  else if(fruitsCount == totalStock) { // should be comparison "==" not assignement "="
    Console.WriteLine("You have just the right amount of fruits!");
  }
  else {
    Console.WriteLine($"You can fit {totalStock - fruitsCount} fruits");
  }
```

Be careful with `string`s: we can't subtract `string` but integers; in your case [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) is the solution (we subtract *integers* within the string):

```
  $"You have too many fruits! Please get rid of {fruitsCount - totalStock} fruits"

  $"You can fit {totalStock - fruitsCount} fruits"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int fruitsCount = fruits["Apples" + "pears"];
```

is wrong.
You can access dictionary values by writing:

```
int fruitsCount = fruits["Apples"] + fruits["pears"];
```

Comment: It _is_ wrong, but it's not the cause of the issue OP is posting about.

Answer (score 1):

```
int fruitsCount = fruits["Apples" + "pears"];
```

is not valid C#. You can use

```
int fruitsCount = fruits["Apples"] + fruits["pears"];
```

or if you want to use LINQ

```
int fruitsCount = fruits.Values.Sum()

else if(fruitsCount = totalStock){
```

should be

```
else if(fruitsCount == totalStock){
```

otherwise you are doing an assignment which you can not do in a if condition.

To make your last subtraction right you need

```
Console.WriteLine($"You can fit { totalStock - fruitsCount } fruits");
```

Comment: It _is_ invalid, but it's not the cause of the issue OP is posting about.

Comment: OP has 3 different errors, this is one of them. Is a partial answer, indeed, but it fixes part of the errors.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 Console.WriteLine($"You can fit {totalStock - fruitsCount} fruits");
```

Comment: I would suggest adding what is the cause of the error and to make it complete, perfect, adding some info on how/why does this code fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have two main errors.

1. `fruits["Apples" + "pears"]` evaluates to `fruits["Applespears"]`. You probably meant `fruits["Apples"] + fruits["pears"]`.
2. Use `==` instead of `=` for equality comparison in the `else if` branch.

Full code:

```
int totalStock = 10;`

Dictionary<string, int> fruits = new Dictionary<string, int>();
fruits.Add("Apples", 3);
fruits.Add("pears", 4);
int fruitsCount = fruits["Apples"] + fruits["pears"];
if(fruitsCount > totalStock){
    // note the added brackets
    Console.WriteLine("You have too many fruits! Please get rid of " + (fruitsCount - totalStock) + " fruits");
}
else if(fruitsCount = totalStock){
    Console.WriteLine("You have just the right amount of fruits!");
}
else{
    Console.WriteLine("You can fit " + (totalStock - fruitsCount) + " fruits");
}
```

Comment: Has 3 error in fact. Your code fixes also "Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'" but forgot to mention it.

Comment: @bradbury9 I did mention it in the comments in the code. I think that's a rather small issue so I didn't say it was a "main" error.

Comment: OP seems new to c#, probably would think "Why are the brackets necessary?"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int totalStock = 10;
            Dictionary<string, int> fruits = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            fruits.Add("Apples", 3);
            fruits.Add("pears", 4);
            int fruitsCount = fruits["Apples"]+ fruits["pears"];
            if (fruitsCount > totalStock)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"You have too many fruits! Please get rid of {fruitsCount - totalStock} fruits");
            }
            else if (fruitsCount == totalStock)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have just the right amount of fruits!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"You can fit { totalStock - fruitsCount } fruits");
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Frist you should learn more about Dictionary, you can find a good info hier: https://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary

I had used list to get all the values of the integer of the fruits as `fruitsValuesCount`. Than i put the list in sum as `fruitsValuesSum`

Hier you can find the right answer:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
namespace Test01
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int totalStock = 10;

            var fruits = new Dictionary<string, int>
            {
                {"Apples", 3},
                {"pears", 4}
            };
            var fruitsValuesCount = new List<int>(fruits.Values);
            var fruitsValuesSum = fruitsValuesCount.Sum();
            int totalFruits = totalStock - fruitsValuesSum;
            if (fruitsValuesSum > totalStock)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have too many fruits! Please get rid of " + totalFruits + " fruits");
            }
            else if (fruitsValuesSum == totalStock)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have just the right amount of fruits!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You can fit " + totalFruits + " fruits");
            }

        }
    }
}
```